# Android, Xamarin: Cannot write to App Preferences via Singleton

Tags: android, xamarin

Im our app, we have a class with app preferences, that stores certain data. A short version of this class looks like this:

```
public class AppPreferences
{
    private ISharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;
    private ISharedPreferencesEditor mPrefsEditor;
    private Context mContext;

    public AppPreferences(Context context)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.Edit();
    }

    public void SaveAutoLogIn(bool autologindone)
    {
        mPrefsEditor.PutBoolean(AUTOLOGIN, autologindone);
        mPrefsEditor.Commit();
    }


    public bool GetSaveAutoLogIn()
    {
       return mSharedPrefs.GetBoolean(AUTOLOGIN, false);
    }


    public void saveLocationPermissionGranted(bool granted)
    {
        mPrefsEditor.PutBoolean(LOCATIONPERMISSION, granted);
        mPrefsEditor.Commit();
    }

    public void savePermissionGranted(bool granted)
    {
        mPrefsEditor.PutBoolean(PERMISSIONS, granted);
        mPrefsEditor.Commit();
    }
```

}

But instead of continuesly instantiating this class in every activity it is needed in, I have decided to create a singleton class (Shorted):

```
class Preferences : AbstractPreferences<Preferences>
{
    // öffentliche Felder und Methoden
    public string usernameKey { get; set; }
    public string emailKey { get; set;  }
    public int numberOfNews { get; set; }
    public bool locationpermission { get; set; }
    public int numberofnewschats { get; set; }

    AppPreferences ap;
    private Preferences()
    {

    }

    public void GetPreferences(Context mContext)
    {
        ap = new AppPreferences(mContext);

        this.usernameKey = ap.getUsernameKey();
        this.emailKey = ap.getEmailKey()

    }

    public void DeletePreferences()
    {
        ap.deletePreferences();
    }

    public void DeleteTutorialPrefs()
    {
        ap.deleteTutorialPrefs();
    }


    public void SetPreferencesDeviceID(string key)
    {
        ap.saveDeviceID(key);
    }
```

}

Okay, so basically, this class that inherets from:

```
public abstract class AbstractPreferences<T> where T : class
{
    // Lazy Instanziierung
    private static readonly Lazy<T> _instance = new Lazy<T>(() => CreateSingletonInstance());

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            //  throw new System.InvalidOperationException("out");
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    private static T CreateSingletonInstance()
    {
        // Konstruktion des Singleton-Objekts
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
    }
}
```

}

Now instantiates all app preferences at once and then sets them to an object like:

```
            Preferences.Preferences prf = Preferences.Preferences.Instance;
    prf.GetPreferences(mContext);
```

This was neccissarry, since any other way caused the app preferences to crash. But here is the problem:

I cannot SET any prefs. Retrieving them works just fine - but when I set a value, like a bool set to true - after I retrieve just this value, I get the default value in return (false). I debugged this as far as I could. When I am in the first class (AppPreferences) I see that the right value is beeing transported into the the final function: For instance:

```
public void SaveAutoLogIn(bool autologindone)
{
    mPrefsEditor.PutBoolean(AUTOLOGIN, autologindone);
    mPrefsEditor.Commit();
}
```

But after retrieving a value from the function I never get was has been set to it. I know, this is a complicated problem - but I really need your guys help. I hope you can help me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you calling `prf.GetPreferences(mContext);` from multiple activities and passing their context in because if that's the case you have a Singleton of `Preferences` but each time you call `GetPreferences` it's creating a different new `AppPreferences` instance with that other context.

Comment: hi. no i am just calling this from this one activity. but i am calling it every time anew when it is instantiated. is that a problem?

Comment: It could be but to be sure I'd change AppPreferences to only be set to `ap = new AppPreferences(mContext);` if the value is null that way you're not creating a new one each time. Also, I do think your settings is a bit more complicated than it needs to be. [Here's an example](https://github.com/nickpeppers/TwitterSafari/blob/master/TwitterSafari/TwitterSafari.Android/Services/AndroidSettings.cs) of what I've done in the past or you could always use the [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) by James Montemagno if you're still having issues.